# I want to write some message when the result is 'no' in gnu prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a code and it is being executed successfully. The code is executed and the result is "yes" when there is result but "no" when there's not. How can I write some message into the gnu prolog terminal when the result is "no". Please. I need your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a predicate `do/1` which either fails or succeeds, this would be the code:

```
do(f) :- fail.
do(t) :- true.

writeyesno(X):-
    (   do(X) 
    ->  write("yes")
    ;   write("no") 
    ).
```

The block `(a -> b ; c)` is an if-then-else-block: if `a`, then `b` else `c`.

Queries (tested with SWISH):

```
?- writeyesno(f).
no
true.

?- writeyesno(t).
yes
true.

?- writeyesno(x).
no
true.
```